# R: Error in model.frame.default(formula = class ~ step + type + amount + :) : object is not a matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, imbalanced-data, oversampling

I am new to R and I am trying to play around with the data from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/ealaxi/paysim1). I try to oversampling it but the `Error in model.frame.default` happen.

1. The first trial

```
oversample_data <- ovun.sample(class ~ ., data = sample_dataset, p = 0.5, seed = 1, method="over")$data
```

But

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = class ~ step + type + amount +
> : object is not a matrix

is shown.

2. That's why I come up with second trial and turn the dataset into matrix first and then do oversampling

```
org_dataset <- as.matrix(org_dataset[complete.cases(org_dataset), ])

data_balanced_over <- ovun.sample(class ~ ., data = org_dataset, p = 0.5, seed = 1, method = "over")$data
```

But it says

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = class ~ step + type + amount +
> : 'data' must be a data.frame, not a matrix or an array

It makes me so confused... What is the right way to do oversampling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the formula you're setting for `ovun.sample`. There is no variable named `class` in the dataset you're referring to.
The [documentation of the ROSE package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROSE/ROSE.pdf) for the formula says that

> The left- hand-side (response) should be a vector specifying the class labels. The right- hand-side should be a series of vectors with the predictors.

Thus, you'll have to specify a variable holding the class labels. Given the dataset, I assume this would be `isFraud`. The call, then would be

```
oversample_data <- ovun.sample(isFraud ~ ., data = sample_dataset, p = 0.5, seed = 1, method="over")$data
```